# Reading recommendation for the chapter 4 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: vector-analysis, book-recommendation, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I just finished the first three chapters from the book *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak. As you should know, a lot of obstacles arise from the chapter 4, "*Integration on Chains*". For example, missed important steps, erratas, bad notation, etc. I really want to read the theory and do the exercise from that book in a detailed way, but the purpose of this post is asking for a "little" help in reading it.

Can you suggest me some additional sources for filling those missing steps, erratas, etc. mentioned before? If it is possible, it would be great if the bibliography that you suggest contains some examples, as an antidote for the abstraction from Spivak.

I know that there exists some excellent books that would be helpful; for example, Munkres's *Analysis on Manifolds*, Ilka Agricola's *Global Analysis*, Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*, and maybe some others. Do you think that those books are enough to deal with the theory from Spivak? Or do you know other sources (lecture notes, videos, etc)?

Any other advice would be well recieved. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You might check out my YouTube videos (linked in my profile). My treatment is less abstract than Spivak's (no tensor products), and I do lots and lots of examples and applications. No chains, either, though. The emphasis is on parametrized submanifolds (so, most frequently, just a chain consisting of a single map).

Comment: I personally read Loomis and Sternberg's chapter 7 on multilinear algebra because I found certain parts of Spivak's chapter 4 unbearable (I read Loomis, Spivak and Munkres, and I found Loomis the nicest... not just this chapter, others as well). After my course on integration on manifolds, I came across Volume 1 of Spivak's Differential Geometry series, and I recall this being a nicer read (more pictures, better explanation)... lol and only after this did I come across @TedShifrin 's lectures...something which I hoped I watched simultaneously while reading chapter 5 of Spivak :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo I heard about Loomis's book before; but most people say that his book is very abstract in content, so do you think that this option is better than Spivak in terms of undertanding?

Comment: Here's my experience: in terms of abstractness of material we have Munkres $\approx$ Spivak $<$ Loomis; this is simply because Loomis and Sternberg do everything in far greater generality (differentiation is done in Banach spaces, abstract definitions of manifolds are given etc). On the other hand, in terms of clarity in writing, Munkres $\approx$ Loomis $<<<<<<<<<$ Spivak. The only reason for this is that this is Spivak's first book, which is written very very concisely and tersely (unlike literally any of his other books:). This is why out of the three, I like Loomis the most.

Comment: The book by Loomis is freely available online, so why not just gloss through it and see for yourself if you like it. Also, there's a book by Hubbard and Hubbard; this is also very nicely written. It develops the subject rigorously, but is very readable. They go through a lot of examples which show you how to actually use the full force of differential forms to actually do calculations (and how it relates to the classical theorems); note that I'm not saying you can't learn computations from Spivak... you can but its that much harder.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your time in answering this question; very admirable. Also, this is not the first time you helped me on related questions haha thanks a lot!